# NSCoder crash on decodeBool forKey (Xcode 8, Swift 3)

Tags: xcode, boolean, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I have this simple class

```
import UIKit

class SimpleModel: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var name : String!
    var done : Bool!

    init(name:String) {
        self.name = name
        self.done = false
    }

    internal required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as! String
        self.done = aDecoder.decodeBool(forKey: "done") // BUG HERE
    }

    func encode(with encoder: NSCoder) {
        encoder.encode(self.name, forKey: "name")
        encoder.encode(self.done, forKey: "done")
    }
}
```

the save code:

```
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: storageArray)
UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "storage")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

the read code:

```
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "storage") {
    storageArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as! [SimpleModel]
}
```

the problem occurs when the NSKeyedUnarchiver does it's job. I can not understand where the problem comes from.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the trick is remove ! form the primitive types.
If you put ! you are saying "make an implicit-unwrapped optional" so the encoder will archive as NSNumber instead of Bool (or Int, Double).
If you remove ! the encoder will archive as Bool and things works as expected (I spent an "incident" and this solution is provided by Apple)

Comment: I could not understand above, I got the solution from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39656687/1298362

Answer (score 12):

`Bool` and `Int` have new methods:

```
 self.x = Int(decoder.decodeCInt(forKey: "Speed"))
 self.y = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "Serial") as! String
 self.z = Bool(decoder.decodeBool(forKey: "Direction") )
```

Comment: Last line can be written simply as: self.z = decoder.decodeBool(forKey: "KeyName"), because decodeBool already returns Bool

Answer (score 8):

I had the same Problem.
Try this:

```
self.done = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "done") as? Bool ?? aDecoder.decodeBool(forKey: "done")
```