# Swift 3: Safe way to decode values with NSCoder?

Tags: swift, swift3

Before Swift 3, you decode boolean values with NSCoder like this:

```
if let value = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(TestKey) as? Bool {
   test = value
}
```

The suggested approach in Swift 3 is to use this instead:

```
aDecoder.decodeBool(forKey: TestKey)
```

But the class reference for `decodeBool` doesn't explain how to handle the situation if the value you're decoding isn't actually a boolean. You can't embed `decodeBool` in a let statement because the return value isn't an optional.

How do you safely decode values in Swift 3?

Comment: If not boolean provided to aDecoder.decodeBool , it raises the error, as it awaits Boolean only. So you have to be sure it is Bool, haven't you?

Comment: right, so it's not a safe way to check @pedrouan. the error would get caught with the swift 2 syntax.

Comment: You have to know which type you are encoding. This is a bit difficult in some cases especially because `Bool` is encoded as `Bool` while `Bool?` is encoded as `Object`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38072295/fail-to-decode-int-with-nscoder-in-swift.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Took me a long time to figure out but you can still decode values like this.
The problem I had with swift3 is the renaming of the encoding methods:

```
// swift2:
coder.encodeObject(Any?, forKey:String)
coder.encodeBool(Bool, forKey:String)

// swift3:
coder.encode(Any?, forKey: String)
coder.encode(Bool, forKey: String)
```

So when you encode a boolean with `coder.encode(boolenValue, forKey: "myBool")` you have to decode it with `decodeBool` but when you encode it like this:

```
let booleanValue = true
coder.encode(booleanValue as Any, forKey: "myBool")
```

you can still decode it like this:

```
if let value = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "myBool") as? Bool {
   test = value
}
```

Comment: Hmmm this looks good, will try it out. Have you used this in production apps?

Comment: Well yes, I converted my swift2 code like this and there are no problems that I know of :-)

Answer (score 6):

This is safe (for shorter code using nil-coalescing op.) when wanted to use suggested decodeBool.

```
let value = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: TestKey) as? Bool ?? aDecoder.decodeBool(forKey: TestKey)
```

Using decodeBool is possible in situations when sure that it's Bool, IMO.

Comment: `TestKey` is the key (and not the value) and is always of type *String*. Most likely, it's even a string constant. So the decoding will never be executed. You're testing the wrong thing.

Comment: @Codo can you elaborate please? TestKey is a string constant. Also do you know the safe way to decode values in Swift 3?

Comment: My comment was referring to the original version of the answer, which was completely different from the current one.